# How to stop string to date in excel using php

Tags: php, excel, csv, phpexcel

Hi i am try to stop string to date in excel sheet csv file using php.
my data is like 10-14 but its convert oct-14. how to solve it using php

my code:-

```php
$delimiter=",";
$fileName="lead-contact-property".date('d-m-y').".csv";

$f=fopen('csv_file/lead-contact-property.csv','w');


$fields = array('Lead id', 'Contact id', 'Property id', 'Type', 'Source', 'Assignee Name', 'Sender Email', 'Spam Score','Is Spam','Subject','Plain Body','Contact Name','Name Salutation','Name Addressee','Contact Email','Primary Info Phone','Property Address Unit Number','Address Street Number','Address Street Name',
'Address Suburb or Town','Address Locality','Address state or Region','Address PostCode','Address Country','Address Estate Name','Address Estate Stage','Property Type','Audit Owned By','Audit Created At','Audit Created By','Audit Last Modified At','Audit Last Modified By');

fputcsv($f, $fields, $delimiter);

while($row=sqlsrv_fetch_array($result,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
{
    
    $audtCreatedAt= date("d/m/Y H:i:s ",$row['audit__created_at']);
    $auditModifyAt=date("d/m/Y H:i:s ",$row['audit_last_modified_at']);

   

    if($row['address_street_number'] !=""){
        $changeStreetNumber=(string)$row['address_street_number'];
        
    }
    
   
    
    $changeUnitNumber=strval($row['property_adr_unit_number']);
    

    $lineData=array($row['lead_id'],$row['contact_id'],$row['property_id'],$row['type'],$row['source'],$row['assignee_name'],$row['sender_email'],
    $row['spam_score'],$row['is_spam'],$row['subject'],$row['plain_body'],$row['contact_name'],$row['name_salutation'],$row['name_addressee'],$row['contact_email'],
    $row['primary_info_phone'],$changeUnitNumber,$changeStreetNumber,$row['address_street_name'],$row['address_suburb_or_town'],$row['address_locality'],
    $row['address_state_or_region'],$row['address_postcode'],$row['address_country'],$row['address_estate_name'],$row['address_estate_stage'],$row['property_type'],
    $row['audit_owned_by'],$audtCreatedAt,$row['audit_created_by'],$auditModifyAt,$row['audit_last_modified_by']);
   
    fputcsv($f, $lineData, $delimiter);
    
}

fseek($f, 0); 

fpassthru($f);
```

Comment: You may be better off using a proper Excel library (maybe the one you've tagged, even though you're not using it) - you're not creating Excel worksheets here, you're creating a CSV file which can then be imported into Excel. Most people (I'm guessing, I haven't done a survey), though, will just double-click it rather than opening a new worksheet and using the "import" facility - the latter will allow them to set column types for each column as it is imported. Sometimes surrounding it with quotes will do the job.

Comment: If you open `csv` file with text editor you should see the correct date. I think your problem with `excel` itself. I would suggest not to use `phpexcel` for `csv` creation. Use `https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter` for `xlsx`. That will help your date format. If you strictly want to use `csv` it's better to calcuate date time from PHP epoch to microsoft epoch style.

Comment: its not date. 10-14 is street and surve number in the address

Comment: Okay so it's easier now just add prefix `'` for `10-14` so make it like this `'10-14`.